# How to remove quotes from an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, regex

Here I have an array.It is an array of time.

```
time = ["19.00","19.01","19.34","19.37","20.05","20.12","10.54","11.12"];
```

I wanted to remove all these quotes.

```
time = [19.00,19.01,19.34,19.37,20.05,20.12,10.54,11.12];
```

Actually, I'm getting all these data from Redis as an array.

And passing data to javascript.

```
var httptime1 = '<?php echo json_encode($httptime1); ?>';
```

i used to remove quotes this way,

```
for (var i = 0; i < time1.length; i++)
{
    time1[i] = time1[i].replace(/"/g, " ");
}
```

But not working.

Can you suggest me, which is the best way?

Comment: the time that is being returned is array of string..you can simply map them to double or float

Comment: check if it's a number using `isNaN()` and use `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` to convert it to a number.

Comment: If you care at all about the *accuracy* of those numbers, you'll want to keep them as a string instead of using *inaccurate floating point numbers*.

Comment: You can simply make `noQuoteTime = time.map(e => e*1)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have quotes in the elements of the JavaScript array. What you have is an array of strings when what you want is an array of numbers.

A solution would be to do the conversion in JavaScript:

```
var httptime1 = <?php echo json_encode($httptime1); ?>.map(Number);
```

But the cleanest one would probably be to convert at the source:

```
var httptime1 = <?php echo json_encode(array_map('floatval', $httptime1)); ?>;
```

**EDIT:**

Those look more like hours:minutes than like some real numbers... Which means numbers are useless. Don't you simply want

```
var httptime1 = <?php echo json_encode($httptime1); ?>;
```

(note that I removed the single quotes which prevented the parsing as a JS literal array in your code)

Comment: Hi, bro. Thank you for answering my question. But i got an error when i used your suggestion. `xyz.php:227 Uncaught TypeError: "["19.00","19.01","19.34","19.37","20.05","20.12","10.54","11.12"]".map is not a function`

Comment: now it's working fine. Thank you, Good explanation. simple and important!

Answer (score 4):

Use `Number` constructor/wrapper object as a callback for `Array.map` function(it will convert each array item into a number):

```
var time = ["19.00","19.01","19.34","19.37","20.05","20.12","10.54","11.12"],
    time_new = time.map(Number);

console.log(time_new); // [19, 19.01, 19.34, 19.37, 20.05, 20.12, 10.54, 11.12]
```

Answer (score 0):

Are these actual quotes or are they strings and you want them to be floats? Because then all you would do is just do a string to number conversion.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using Number function which change string to number.

```
var time = ["19.00","19.01","19.34","19.37","20.05","20.12","10.54","11.12"];
time.forEach(function(a,i){time[i]=Number(a)});  
console.log(time);
```